# Is it possible to load GCed libraries from a program that merely 'supports' it?

Tags: macos, garbage-collection, dynamic-linking

I have a command-line executable from which I would like to be able load essentially any dynamic library that contains Objective-C classes. In the Project Settings, I have specified that my program *supports* garbage collection (without requiring it). To this end, I use `dlopen` to load the libraries, as it's globally more flexible than `NSBundle` (first off and most importantly, it can load libraries that aren't in a bundle).

However, when I try to load a library or framework that *requires* garbage collection, `dlopen` fails and I get this message:

> Unable to open /path/to/object: dlopen(/path/to/lib, 2): no
>   suitable image found.  Did find:
>          /path/to/lib: GC capability mismatch

If my program supports garbage collection, why can't it load libraries that require it? How can I load libraries that require it?

I can't really flag my executable as *requiring* garbage collection because it will stop working with libraries that don't support it.

Right now I have two versions of my executable, but that's sub-par.

**Additional informations**: I target Mountain Lion only. My program is a universal binary and it currently handles relaunching as its 32-bits counterpart using the `posix_spawn` function, however there seems to be no flag controlling garbage collection there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. [The Objective-C runtime has several switches triggered by environment variables](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-runtime.mm?txt), including `OBJC_DISABLE_GC` that can turn off the garbage collector even if the executable wants it on. [This switch is taken into account when new images are loaded](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/runtime/objc-os.m) (see `gc_enforcer` and how it uses the `UseGC` static variable), so turning the GC off will actually affect the way libraries are loaded into the process.

My solution, then, is to implement proper retain/release logic into my executable but compile it with `-fobjc-gc-only`. I then try to load the library normally; if it works, everything's good. If it doesn't, I programmatically relaunch the process with the same arguments, plus `OBJC_DISABLE_GC=YES` in its environment, so the GC is disabled and the library successfully loads this time.

This snippet excludes error handling.

```c
char disableGC[] = "OBJC_DISABLE_GC=YES";
// resets the current process with the given argv and enables the GC as per useGC
void respawn(char* const argv[], bool useGC)
{
    posix_spawnattr_t attributes;
    posix_spawnattr_init(&attributes);
    posix_spawnattr_setflags(&attributes, POSIX_SPAWN_SETEXEC)

    // build the environment variables array
    std::vector<char*> environment;
    for (char** environ_iter = environ; *environ_iter != 0; environ_iter++)
        environment.push_back(*environ_iter);

    // disable the GC if we need it off
    if (!useGC)
    {
        environment.push_back(disableGC);
    }

    environment.push_back(nullptr);

    pid_t child;
    posix_spawn(&child, argv[0], nullptr, &attributes, argv, environment.data());
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me, please, how update xcode project with this code. Where should I add this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To load a Garbage Collected library, your executable must be running in a garbage-collected environment to start with. You'll need to either:

- Always run under GC
- Detect that the library requires GC and relaunch using GC, then retry loading the library. Kinda like how System Preferences will relaunch itself for 32bit panes.

Comment: Relaunching with the GC would be an acceptable solution; how could I do it? I know I can use `posix_spawn` to relaunch in a 32-bits environment, but it doesn't seem to also include controls to enable the garbage collector.